# iPhone - how to remove black space beneath the navigation bar after reducing the height

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, frame

I had to adjust the height of the UINavigationBar for this iPhone app.
Now when I use the smaller navBar in a tableview, there is a black space beneath it.

I would like to see it gone...

Can anyone help me? Much appreciated!

visual: http://tinypic.com/r/2gwchg2/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your navigation bar frame and make it above reduce y direction in frame.Try this.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);
```

Make it y=-10 and height=30; and check and adjust according your requirement.

```
UIView *BtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,30)];
UILabel *compete_Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 60, 20)];
[compete_Label setText:@"Your Title name"];

compete_Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[compete_Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
compete_Label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[BtnView addSubview:compete_Label];
[self.View addSubView:BtnView];
```

Try this code I think that will be work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response vishiphone.
I tried the solution you suggested, the black space is still there.

Comment: Check your view background color is it black?

Comment: I wish, it's pure white! That was one of the first things I checked.

Comment: Ok then i gave u another solution also just wait for a minute.

Comment: I've waited some minutes now :D I'm still stuck with the black space!

Comment: Remove navigation bar from view try that first then add own custom view instant of navigation bar.When you remove navigation bar check there is black screen or not.

Comment: If I hide the navBar, the black space is gone as well

Comment: Then now if your black space it not there then its good now add one custom view or navigation bar in there.

Comment: Could you explain that last comment a bit further please?

Comment: now you add your own custom navigation bar or you can just add one view there because I think on your navigation bar no button you used so try with view create one view and add that view on self.view. and one more thing tommy if you want more help from my side please give me some favor up my arrow sign because from last week I spent my more time to help him out but after slove his problem they avoid the comments.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but this is not the solution I am looking for. I still need the back function on the navigation bar. Replacing the navigation bar with a label in a subview is not what I need.

PS I can't favour you up, because I need more reputation or something

Comment: Ok then can also add custom button on that if you want but its ok your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the navigation bar smaller, then you should make the tableview frame position accordingly such that its origin-y to be set to bottom of the navigation bar.

Set the tableview origin-y and adjust the height of the tableview.

Comment: Hey Aadhira, thanks for your response. I've tried using something like this: [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, 320, 480)];

However, the tableview does not move....